# Mysterious scrolling issue after adding image mouse-overs

Tags: html, css

I have a [page](http://pages.suddenlink.net/dewitt/) that exhibits a mysterious scrolling problem after adding some image mouse-overs.  The problem goes away if I take the mouse-overs out.  Some relevant parts of my CSS:

```
body {
  width: 970px;
  background: url(notebook.png) repeat-y;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font: 1em "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
}
table {
  width: 970px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: you mean the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Correct.  I don't understand how the addition of `<span class="static"><img class="square" ...><span><img class="block" ...></span></span>` could cause this.

Comment: Look at my answer below, I corrected your problem :)

Comment: I just noticed your change in your production environment. Just need to tell you that you don't need that `visibility: visible;` anymore in your `.static:hover span` selector in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see an horizontall scroll because the image is there making space in your HTML document. You should hide it when it is not showing with `display:none;` and giving `display: block;` or `display: initial;` when it is showing.

You have

```
.static span {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

But `visibility: hidden;` just hiddes the element but still makes the space, work it with `display: none;`

**UPDATE**

Change this:

```
.static span {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

to this:

```
.static span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

And this:

```
.static:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

To this:

```
.static:hover span {
    display: initial;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

And problem solved :)